# How would you go about implementing conditional imports similar to ReactNative?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

How would you go about implementing conditional imports similar to how React Native imports Android or iOS specific classes using `*.android.js` and `*.ios.js` respectively.

How would I go about doing something similar to that (not necessarily in a ReactNative project) for other reasons. For example, if I wanted to have specific classes for development and production, how would I be able to use `*.dev.js` and `*.prod.js` respectively?

I'm sure there's a way to do so given ReactNative is able to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one way (using Webpack) would be

```
//webpack config file

...
resolve: {
    extensions: [(/*condition*/) ? '.ext1.js' : '.ext2.js', '.js' ]
}
```

However, this solution doesn't seems ideal, so if someone has a better way of going about it, please share. Or let me know if I'm mistaken and this is a good solution.